# Magit git diff between two specific SHAs

Tags: magit, git

Using git cli I would execute

`git diff SHA#1 SHA#2`

How does one do the equivalent in magit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the diff range command with the `..` syntax:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> `SHA#1..SHA#2`

Refer to the git diff man page:

```
   git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.

   git diff [--options] <commit>..<commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is synonymous to the previous form. If <commit> on one side is omitted,
       it will have the same effect as using HEAD instead.

   git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second
       <commit>, starting at a common ancestor of both <commit>. "git diff A...B" is
       equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of
       <commit>, which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.
```

Note that you can type both commits with completion (but you have to type the `..` before completion for the second kicks in).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! 
I did work out that one can 'branch'-'check out' ("b")("c") to the later of the two SHAs of interest.  
Then run 'diff-'Diff range' ("d")("r"), where you can specify the second (earlier) SHA. But being able to specify both SHAs like you have highlighted is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

If both commits are near each other in some Magit buffer, then it might be convenient to mark them using the region and then pressing <kbd>d d</kbd>. With such an active region "diff dwim" assumes that you want to compare the commits at the edge of the region.

<kbd>d r</kbd> works always. It might just be a bit annoying to type or copy-paste hashes.

Comment: Cool thanks @tarsius. Did not know about this. Well first thing is finding the hash. I was using `y` when in the logging screen. Useful for big code bases that use version tagging. Allows me to diff between versions. So yes, using this alternate method can be very useful.